# Take From a List While Increasing

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of values that I would like to take from while the value is increasing. I assume it would always take the head of the list and then compare it to the next value. The function will continue to take as long as this continues to increase. Upon reaching an list element that is less than or equal the pervious value the list is returned.

```
takeIncreasing :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
takeIncreasing [1,2,3,4,3,5,6,7,8] -- Should return [1,2,3,4]
```

A fold could compare the `last` element of  the accumulation with the next value and append if the condition is met, but would continue to the end of the list. I would like the function to stop taking at the first instance the constraint is not met.

This seems like an application of a monad but cannot determine if an existing monad accomplishes this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A fold [...] would continue to the end of the list. I would like the function to stop taking at the first instance the constraint is not met.

A right fold can short circuit:

```
fun :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
fun []     = []
fun (x:xs) = x: foldr go (const []) xs x
    where go x f i = if i < x then x: f x else []
```

then,

```
\> fun [1,2,3,4,3,undefined]
[1,2,3,4]
```

or infinite size list:

```
\> fun $ [1,2,3,4,3] ++ [1..]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Nitpick: a right fold can short-circuit **in a lazily evaluated language** like Haskell. But this is of course a very important point to know!  Many people who come to Haskell have experience with eagerly evaluated languages, where right folds are often shunned because they (a) continue to the end of the list and (b) blow the stack on long lists. But Haskell's `foldr` can be and is often used in ways that don't have that problem—and in fact, in Haskell `foldl` is the one that more often risks blowing the stack!

Answer (score 4):

Right folds are magical, so you never even have to pattern match on the list.

```
twi xs = foldr go (const []) xs Nothing where
  go x _ (Just prev)
    | x < prev = []
  go x r _ = x : r (Just x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or one that IMO has a bit less code complexity:

```
takeIncreasing :: Ord x => [x] -> [x]
takeIncreasing (x:x':xs) | x < x'    = x : takeIncreasing (x':xs)
                         | otherwise = [x]
takeIncreasing xs = xs
```

This one is just a bit less clever than previous suggestions. I like un-clever code.

Answer (score 2):

A solution without folds:

```
takeIncreasing :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
takeIncreasing [] = []
takeIncreasing (x:xs) = (x :) . map snd . takeWhile (uncurry (<)) $ zip (x:xs) xs
```